# Can the word 'sumptuous' be replaced by 'luxurious'?

Tags: differences, vocabulary, single-word-requests

Can the word 'sumptuous' be replaced by 'luxurious' in the following sentence:

> Kevin's classmates were invited to his birthday party where a **sumptuous** meal awaited them.

Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely it can.

Comment: If you look at the dictionary definitions, *luxurious* connotes "a surrender to physical comfort leading to a delightful feeling of well-being: They stayed in a luxurious suite with a crystal chandelier and thick oriental rugs." Sumptuous connotes "entailing great expense, as from choice materials." It is often used of food. They are interchangeable, but sumptuous is a better word for food.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They can, though sumptuous is often used in the sense of '(more than) satisfactory' meal and luxurious is used in the sense of meal being expensive.

*Update* to give ref/eg
Sumptuous: Of a size or splendor suggesting great expense; lavish: "He likes big meals, so I cook sumptuous ones" (Src: FreeDictionary)
Luxurious: Providing great pleasure or comfort, especially at great cost: "luxurious bedsheets that were made of silk"

Comment: Please support your answer with sources. That makes your answer stronger, and more likely to be viewed as correct. Otherwise, even if it's correct, it's likely to be viewed as only opinion. The [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) will give you guidance on how to use this site.